# How to exclude changes when commiting in VSTS / Azure devops?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

When using TFS, it is simple to exclude changes in Visual studio just by right clicking.

How can I do the same in VSTS which is now Azure devops? I have a repository with multiple solutions and i only want selected changes in a particular solution to be committed and pushed to the server. But how to perform this operation?

Comment: Are you using TFVC or Git?

Comment: There is literally zero difference between VSTS/Azure DevOps and TFS in this regard.

Comment: Although that's partially true, there _are_ big differences between Git and TFVC which used to be the default source control solution in TFS. When both environments use Git, there's no difference. When the new environment uses Git while the old used TFVC, there are differences.

Comment: @rickvdbosch Sure. But this person wasn't asking about differences between TFVC and Git. They were asking about differences between Azure DevOps and TFS. There are none, at least when it comes to version control.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using Git, you can *stage* changes you want to commit. If you have staged changes, all other *unstaged* changes will not be part of the commit. Staging a file is simply preparing it to be committed.

[image: Git local changes]

When you do not *stage* changes in Visual Studio, by default *all changes* are committed. See the left side of the image below: the button says 'Commit all'. The changes are all grouped together. If you commit like this, all changes would be committed.

In the right part of the image, you can see there are Changes, and **Staged** Changes. The commit button's text has changed to 'Commit Staged'. If you commit like this, the `Notifications.cs` file *would* be part of the commit, the `News.cs` *would not* be part of the commit.

You can (un)stage changes in Visual Studio by right clicking them and selecting (un)stage. You can also selecting the files to (un)stage and using the plus sign at the top right of the Changes to stage, and the minus sign at the top og the Staged Changes to unstage.

[image: No staged vs staged changes]

In short: by staging changes, you can determine which changes are included in the commit you're about to create. Here's some more information on [Git Basics](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics), the below information about staging can be found at the bottom of that article.

> The staging area is a file, generally contained in your Git directory, that stores information about what will go into your next commit. Its technical name in Git parlance is the “index”, but the phrase “staging area” works just as well.
>
> The basic Git workflow goes something like this:
>
> 1. You modify files in your working tree.
> 2. You selectively stage just those changes you want to be part of your next commit, which adds only those changes to the staging area.
> 3. You do a commit, which takes the files as they are in the staging area and stores that snapshot permanently to your Git directory.

Comment: Too bad you have to piecemeal stage a bunch of changes in order to exclude one.  It used to be you could do the inverse, select one change to exclude, and commit all the others.  The work flow when you have a lot of changes to commit and one or two files that need to be excluded is painful.